# window.location.href cancels async calls to API

Tags: javascript, ajax

When the code runs window.location.href kicks in before all async calls to the API is done. If I set a breakpoint on the location it works fine.

How can wait until all calls are done before invoking window.location.href?

Code:

```
const saveInvoice = async () => {
    if (containsItems()) {
        let customerId = document.getElementById("Customer").value;
        let date = document.getElementById("Date").value;
        let dueDate = document.getElementById("DueDate").value;
        let msgKID = document.getElementById("MSG").value;
        let accountId = document.getElementById("Account").value;
        let data = await WebRequest("InvoiceAPI", "CreateInvoiceAsync", null, { "CustomerId": customerId, "Date": date, "DueDate": dueDate, "MsgKID": msgKID, "AccountId": accountId });

        getLineNumbers().forEach(async (nr) => {
            let prodId = parseInt(document.querySelector('select.prod[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"]').value);
            let descr = document.querySelector('input.description[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"]').value;
            let price = parseFloat(document.querySelector('span.price[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"] > span.sum').innerHTML);
            let mva = parseInt(document.querySelector('span.mva[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"] > span.sum').innerHTML);
            let mvaSum = parseFloat(document.querySelector('input.mva-value[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"]').value)
            let count = parseInt(document.querySelector('input.count[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"]').value);
            let perc = parseInt(document.querySelector('input.perc[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"]').value);
            let sum = parseFloat(document.querySelector('#Lines > div.line.row > div.amount-wrap[data-id=\"' + nr + '\"] span.line-sum').innerHTML);

            await WebRequest("InvoiceAPI", "CreateInvoiceLineAsync", null, { "InvoiceId": data.json.id, "ProductId": prodId, "Description": descr, "Count": count, "Discount": perc, "Price": price, "Mva": mva, "MvaSum": mvaSum, "Sum": sum });
        });

        window.location.href = "View/" + data.json.uId;
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("InvoiceErrorWrap").classList.remove("hide");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for an array of `Promise`s to be completed. (`Array#forEach` is not designed to work with `Promise`s.)

Here, we can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create an array containing a `Promise` for each element in the array returned by `getLineNumbers()`.

```js
await Promise.all(getLineNumbers().map(async nr => {
    // other code...
    await WebRequest("InvoiceAPI", "CreateInvoiceLineAsync", null, { "InvoiceId": data.json.id, "ProductId": prodId, "Description": descr, "Count": count, "Discount": perc, "Price": price, "Mva": mva, "MvaSum": mvaSum, "Sum": sum });
}));
// set location here
```

Answer (score 0):

Each individual asynchronous operation appears to internally `await`, but nothing is awaiting all of those operations.  More literally, `saveInvoice` is `async` but it doesn't `await` anything.

You can replace the call to `.forEach()` with a call to `.map()` to return the promises:

```
const promises = getLineNumbers().map(async (nr) => {
  //...
});
```

Then await those promises:

```
await Promise.all(promises);
window.location.href = "View/" + data.json.uId;
```